# Anti-CSRF tokens randomly mismatch in AJAX requests called on page load

Tags: php, ajax, csrf

I have implemented an `anti-csrf` token system for my website. It works fine; but when I try to refresh a certain page, or sometimes when I double-click the link of a certain page, at times csrf token and the session holding the created token mismatch. I have no ideas what is causing the problem, but I think it must be a case of race or something. Here, in this scenario, I assume one request is being sent to the server, the token is being sent along, and just at the same time the page gets refreshed and another session is created. What shows up here here is an old token and a newly refreshed session with new token.

```
// I just start the session, currently with no options passed.
doStartSession();

// Then I create a random token.
$token = sha1(random_bytes(32));
// Finally I start the session, the second argument here is the key for the session.
csrfSession($token, 'csrf-for-this-page');


/* I save the created token in a meta tag as well */
<meta name="csrf-for-this-page" content="<?php echo $token; ?>" />

/* The AJAX call */
$.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'some-url.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {"reachData": 'true',
              "csrf-for-this-page": $('meta[name="csrf-for-this-page"]').attr('content'),
            }
       })
```

In fact, the problem is the randomness of token mismatch, and it just happens with the AJAX requests that are called at `document.ready` when the page loads. Other AJAX requests called at link or button click just work as expected, and does not run into any problems. For these unexpected behavior at page load, I have tried to wait one second and then call the AJAX request using `setTimeout` function. That was fine, yet not that user-friendly, and I thought to keep it as the last resort, if no other solutions were offered.

I wanted to ask what am I missing here? Is what happening here to me normal or abnormal, under the circumstances that a page loads in a rapid concession? If its abnormal how should I solve the problem?
I was thinking of what we do to prevent double submission; that is using `beforesend`.
For the links and buttons that start AJAX requests, we normally use this to disable the link or button when the request is being sent and then after `success`, we just enable them. I wonder if there could be any possible ways to prevent AJAX requests when another is being sent. Nothing came to my mind, and I am not that positive if there are any possible ways to do the trick.

Regarding what I just said, I wanted your professional ideas on how to solve the problem. How to prevent this random token mismatch in AJAX requests called at page load.

Comment: You're simply changing the tokens too often. Suppose that everything, between arriving at your website and then leaving your website, is a single session, then the token for a specific AJAX call doesn't need to change during such a session.

Comment: Dear @KIKOSoftware, Thanks for mentioning that. In fact, after reading OWASP on Cross-Site Forgery, I made sure that there is no problem with `per session tokens`. Here, however,  I just wanted to know if I could solve the problem under current circumstances or not?

Comment: The way I do it is: When I user logs into my site I generate a new master CSRF token. For each data submission I combine this master token with a fixed other token to create a specific token for that submission. That token stays the same while the user is logged in. This way the token will never change during weird refresh and submit events.

Comment: No, there's no good solution if you change the token on every page reload.

Comment: It's not terribly complicated. Tokens are made with `bin2hex(random_bytes(24))` which generates something like: "cdfd7cf5482dea331e27267830ead5216503a6b4230875b3". A master token like this is stored in the database when an user logs in. In a form, or an AJAX call, I combine this token with a "seed", [hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.hash.php) that, and supply it as a data value. When I check it on the other end, I do the same to reconstruct that data value and compare it with the value received. You can vary this quite a bit, as long as you don't update the token too often.

Comment: The "seed" is just a fixed string, usually the name of the form, or what the AJAX call does. The reason I use these "seeds" is to make the CSRF token different for all the possible different calls. It's not needed, but a nice feature. This way a bad user cannot cross-post a CSRF token.

Comment: Dear @KIKOSoftware, your tips and comments are great. Since you spent some time reading my post and commenting on it, if possible just present a simple code of adding hash to the token, so that I can make it up with an upvote. Or simply send your comments as an answer.